# to_json y read_json en Python Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

Estoy tratando de pasar un `DataFrame` o Serie en Python a formato JSON con `to_json()` y volver a leerlo con `read_json()`, pero me lo guarda o recupera con formato equivocado.

La serie que trato de convertir es:

```
pmes['ADS']['Junio']['RentabilidadAcumulada']
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

E introduzco la siguiente orden:

```
x=pmes['ADS']['Junio']['RentabilidadAcumulada'].to_json(orient='split')
```

Cuando lo trato de volver a leer, me devuelve:

```
pd.read_json(x)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si lo leo con:

```
pd.read_json(x,orient='split')
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-21-3295766ce414>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.read_json(x,orient='split')

  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 366, in read_json
    return json_reader.read()

  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 467, in read
    obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)

  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 484, in _get_object_parser
    obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()

  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 576, in parse
    self._parse_no_numpy()

  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 799, in _parse_no_numpy
    self.check_keys_split(decoded)

  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 566, in check_keys_split
    .format(bad_keys=pprint_thing(bad_keys)))

ValueError: JSON data had unexpected key(s): name
```

¿Alguien me podría ayudar a pasar la Serie a formato JSON y volver a recuperarla en el mismo formato de Serie?. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Usa `typ='series'`. En Pandas, `read_json()` por defecto trata de leer  como dataframe, pero en este caso es una serie.

Para más referencia visita esta [pregunta el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965985/pandas-series-to-json-and-back).